# speech-dispatcher voice configuration problems with festival

Tags: text-to-speech, festival, speech-dispatcher

I finally got `Festival` working with the US HTS voices: `cmu_us_awb_cg`, `cmu_us_jmk_cg`, `cmu_us_slt_cg`, `cmu_us_bdl_cg`, `cmu_us_clb_cg`, `cmu_us_rms_cg`.

I manually configured `festival.scm` to use `bdl` voice:

```
 (set! voice_default 'voice_cmu_us_bdl_cg)
```

It's now working fine both from within interactive `festival` and when server is running (`festival --server`):

```
nc localhost 1314 <<< "(tts_text \"Hello big world, this is a test.\" nil)(quit)"
```

I then configured speech-dispatcher, it failed to properly configure itself via `spd-conf`, but I manually fixed the configuration file`speechd`. To sum it up:

```
LogLevel  3
LogDir  "default"
DefaultRate  5
DefaultVolume 100    
DefaultLanguage "en"
DefaultPunctuationMode "all"
AudioOutputMethod "alsa"
AudioALSADevice "default"
AddModule "festival"     "sd_festival"  "festival.conf"
AddModule "dummy"         "sd_dummy"      ""
DefaultModule festival
LanguageDefaultModule "en"  "festival"
Include "clients/*.conf"
```

Now ALSA test is working fine (producing sound). However, when I send a text to `speech-dispatcher`:

```
spd-say "Hello big world, this is a test."
```

...the `festival` server goes crazy, like it was unsuccessfully trying each and every voice it can think of:

```
SIOD: unknown voice cmu_us_ahw_cg
SIOD: unknown voice cmu_us_ahw_cg
SIOD: unknown voice cmu_us_aup_cg
SIOD: unknown voice cmu_us_aup_cg
SIOD: unknown voice cmu_us_awb_cg
SIOD: unknown voice cmu_us_awb_cg
SIOD: unknown voice cmu_us_axb_cg
SIOD: unknown voice cmu_us_axb_cg
SIOD: unknown voice cmu_us_bdl_cg
SIOD: unknown voice cmu_us_bdl_cg
SIOD ERROR: could not open file /usr/share/festival/dicts/oald/oaldlex.scm
closing a file left open: /usr/share/festival/voices/english/rab_diphone/festvox/rab_diphone.scm
SIOD: unknown voice rab_diphone
SIOD ERROR: could not open file /usr/share/festival/dicts/oald/oaldlex.scm
closing a file left open: /usr/share/festival/voices/english/rab_diphone/festvox/rab_diphone.scm
SIOD: unknown voice rab_diphone
SIOD: unknown voice cmu_us_kal_com_hts
SIOD: unknown voice cmu_us_kal_com_hts
SIOD: unknown voice cstr_us_ked_timit_hts
SIOD: unknown voice cstr_us_ked_timit_hts
SIOD: unknown voice cmu_us_slt_cg
SIOD: unknown voice cmu_us_slt_cg
SIOD: unknown voice cmu_us_rms_cg
SIOD: unknown voice cmu_us_rms_cg
SIOD: unknown voice cmu_us_awb_cg
SIOD: unknown voice cmu_us_awb_cg
SIOD: unknown voice cmu_us_bdl_cg
SIOD: unknown voice cmu_us_bdl_cg
SIOD ERROR: ran out of storage 
closing a file left open: /usr/share/festival/voices/us/cmu_us_clb_cg//rf_models/trees_08/cmu_us_clb_mcep.tree
SIOD: unknown voice cmu_us_clb_cg
SIOD ERROR: ran out of storage 
closing a file left open: /usr/share/festival/voices/us/cmu_us_clb_cg//festival/trees/cmu_us_clb_mcep.tree
SIOD: unknown voice cmu_us_clb_cg
client(10) Mon Mar 16 22:10:26 2020 : accepted from localhost
SIOD: unknown voice cmu_us_ahw_cg
SIOD: unknown voice cmu_us_aup_cg
SIOD: unknown voice cmu_us_awb_cg
SIOD: unknown voice cmu_us_axb_cg
SIOD: unknown voice cmu_us_bdl_cg
SIOD ERROR: could not open file /usr/share/festival/dicts/oald/oaldlex.scm
closing a file left open: /usr/share/festival/voices/english/rab_diphone/festvox/rab_diphone.scm
SIOD: unknown voice rab_diphone
SIOD: unknown voice cmu_us_kal_com_hts
SIOD: unknown voice cstr_us_ked_timit_hts
SIOD: unknown voice cmu_us_slt_cg
SIOD: unknown voice cmu_us_rms_cg
SIOD: unknown voice cmu_us_awb_cg
SIOD: unknown voice cmu_us_bdl_cg
SIOD ERROR: ran out of storage 
closing a file left open: /usr/share/festival/voices/us/cmu_us_clb_cg//rf_models/trees_08/cmu_us_clb_mcep.tree
SIOD: unknown voice cmu_us_clb_cg
SIOD ERROR: ran out of storage 
closing a file left open: /usr/share/festival/voices/us/cmu_us_jmk_cg//festival/trees/cmu_us_jmk_mcep.tree
SIOD: unknown voice cmu_us_jmk_cg
SIOD: unknown voice cmu_us_ahw_cg
SIOD: unknown voice cmu_us_ahw_cg
SIOD: unknown voice cmu_us_aup_cg
SIOD: unknown voice cmu_us_aup_cg
SIOD: unknown voice cmu_us_awb_cg
SIOD: unknown voice cmu_us_awb_cg
```

**So, festival is working, connection to ALSA is working, speech-dispatcher is sending something to the festival, but it's somehow broken, possibly wrong voice settings.**

There is also a configuration file for festival module within `/etc/speech-dispatcher/modules/` folder, `festival.conf`, but it's virtually empty (with a lot of commented text) and it does not mention anything about voices set by `speech-dispatcher` when calling the `Festival`. It's a place I would assume one can set that, especially because a comment in `speechd.conf`:

> The DefaultVoiceType controls which voice type should be used by
>   default.  Voice types are symbolic names which map to particular
>   voices provided by the synthesizer according to the output module
>   configuration.  Please see the synthesizer-specific configuration
>   in etc/speech-dispatcher/modules/ to see which voices are assigned to
>   different symbolic names.  The following symbolic names are
>   currently supported: MALE1, MALE2, MALE3, FEMALE1, FEMALE2, FEMALE3,
>   CHILD_MALE, CHILD_FEMALE
>
> # DefaultVoiceType  "MALE1"

I also tried to increase heap size up to 50M (as per some posts in other discussions), but it doesn't help:

```
festival --server --heap 50000000
```

I get the same strange errors. Any suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

To solve this issue need to define `(proclaim_voice` in `scm` file.
please refer below steps:

1. go to festival/voices folder
2. edit scm file

   - open:

     ```
     vim us/cmu_us_clb_arctic_clunits/festvox/cmu_us_clb_arctic_clunits.scm   #<--voice clunits.scm
     ```
   - Go to bottom of file add line before `(provide 'cmu_us_clb_arctic_clunits)`
   - Add below content (update language, gender, dialect as needed). Update, save and quit.

     ```
     (proclaim_voice
      'cmu_us_clb_arctic_clunits
      '((language english)
        (gender female)
        (dialect american)
        (description
         "This voice provides an American English male voice using a
          residual excited LPC diphone synthesis method.  It uses
          the CMU Lexicon pronunciations.  Prosodic phrasing is provided
          by a statistically trained model using part of speech and local
          distribution of breaks.  Intonation is provided by a CART tree
          predicting ToBI accents and an F0 contour generated from a model
          trained from natural speech.  The duration model is also trained
          from data using a CART tree.")))
     ```
3. After `/usr/bin/festival --server` the error should be gone

You could also run `spd-say -L` to show the details.

If need to update default festival voice:

- Edit `/etc/festival.scm` to add

  ```
  (set! voice_default 'voice_<You prefered Voice name>)
  ```
- restart festival server or reboot ubuntu. The default voice will be changed to new one via `spd-say` command or from Firefox.

Comment: Thank you Heng, looks like a solution, I'll test (within a week or so) it and report back. I was recently working with a different component that did not have a TTS solution for Linux, so we agreed with the devolper that I'd write a little "speech-dispatcher" for MaryTTS. I did that, but the developer seem to cease working on the project... Anyhow, I'll try to follow your steps to make the original component work with spd and Festival as you suggested.

Comment: `/etc/festival.scm` this file doesn't exist on manjaro

Comment: what is `<You preferred voice name>`? I have no idea what to put there. Can you please give examples for English?

Answer (score -1):

The problem could be because `speech-dispatcher` is not accepting festival's default voice, instead, it tries to use its own settings.

Try uncommenting and changing the `DefaultVoiceType` to something like:

`DefaultVoiceType "FEMALE1"`

I'd also do some testing using different programs, like Firefox's reader mode (ALT+CTRL+R) and see if you get any of the listed voices working.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I'll have a look at it once again and report back.

Comment: what file do you add this to?